# Convert Excel spreadsheet to HTML table, keep hyperlinks in cell text

Tags: html, excel, hyperlink, type-conversion, export

I am looking to convert a spreadsheet into a HTML table. My current issue is that most Excel to HTML tools do not keep hyperlinks in cells.

For example, say I have an Excel sheet with the word 'Google' in a cell, which contains a hyperlink to 'www.google.com'.

When using common online tools to convert Excel table to HTML table ([example](https://tools.agsci.psu.edu/table-maker/)), it would output the cell like this:

```
<td>Google</td>
```

**What I am ideally hoping for instead is this** (ideally with the target="_blank" to open in new window):

```
<td><a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></td>
```

**Notes:**

1. I am currently using the VBA script from this page to convert Excel data into HTML format: https://gist.github.com/shapiromatron/5024948?permalink_comment_id=2985716
2. Another example conversion tool is this: https://tools.agsci.psu.edu/table-maker/
3. I am not committed to any method. Currently using Excel, but happy to use Google Sheets (or other) if easier,
4. I'm also happy to not use spreadsheets at all, however, I'll be regularly updating the data and creating a lot of tables, so figured spreadsheets were the easiest source to maintain?!
5. As a last resort, I can also export to JSON instead of HTML, if there is a solution that way.

Many thanks in advance for any guidance or tips you may have :)

Comment: Did you try "Return Table Data as JSON" on Excel Automate tab / Samples?